# GGplot2 Change legend items

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have more legend items due to a time course but I only want to show two labels : Healthy and Patient.

```
## Construct the data
healthy <- rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=1)
patientTimeA <- rnorm(100,mean=1,sd=1)
patientTimeB <- rnorm(100,mean=3,sd=1)
patientTimeC <- rnorm(100,mean=4,sd=1)
groupArray <- c(rep("H",100),rep("P",300))
timeArray <- c(rep(0,100),rep(10,100),rep(20,100),rep(30,100))
dataTab <- data.frame(group=groupArray,time=timeArray,value=c(healthy,patientTimeA,patientTimeB,patientTimeC))
dataTab$group <- paste(dataTab$group,dataTab$time,sep="_")

  colVector <- c("red","blue","blue","blue")

  p <- ggplot(dataTab,aes(x=group,y=value,fill=group)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.7)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colVector) 
  print(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create two different variables in your dataTab for the X and the fill aesthetics:

```
healthy <- rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
patientTimeA <- rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 1)
patientTimeB <- rnorm(100, mean = 3, sd = 1)
patientTimeC <- rnorm(100, mean = 4, sd = 1)
groupArray <- c(rep("H", 100),rep("P", 300))
timeArray <- c(rep(0, 100), rep(10, 100), rep(20, 100), rep(30, 100))
dataTab <- data.frame(group = groupArray, time = timeArray, 
                      value = c(healthy, patientTimeA, patientTimeB, patientTimeC))
dataTab$group1 <- paste(dataTab$group, dataTab$time, sep = "_")
colVector <- c("red", "blue", "blue", "blue")

p <- ggplot(dataTab, aes(x = group1, y = value, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colVector) 
print(p)
```

[image]